# Split elements into sections

Tags: xslt-3.0, xpath-3.0

I'd like to split a text into sections:

The source XML:

```
<data>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>nice</p>
  <p>BREAK</p>
  <p>world</p>
</data>
```

My half successful attempt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with=".[. = 'BREAK']">
      <chapter>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </chapter>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result (fragment) I'd like to get:

```
<chapter>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>nice</p>
</chapter>
<chapter>
  <p>world</p>
</chapter>
```

Instead I get

```
<chapter>
   <p>hello</p>
   <p>nice</p>
</chapter>
<chapter>
   <p>BREAK</p>
   <p>world</p>
</chapter>
```

(it still contains `<p>BREAK</p>`)

My question is: is there a straightforward way to get rid of the `<p>BREAK</p>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily select `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(. = 'BREAK')]"/>`.